# Tool to extract a DB row and ALL its referenced "objects" (recursively)?

Tags: sql, oracle

For our project it has become increasingly complicated to reproduce certain error conditions that show up in productive use. Extracting and recreating certain conditions sometimes takes hours to re-enter the data and reproduce a situation mainly because the required "graph" can be huge and there are many referential constraints that must be fulfilled and recreating these in an analysis DB (production can not be used for this for obvious reasons) in the correct order is often extremely complicated and tedious.

What would ease such analyses enormously would be some tool that - given a specific table and row-id as starting point - would traverse the entire graph as defined by a table's references (foreign keys) and emit all referenced entries recursively. 
Ideally it would emit all these rows (table name, column names and their values) as sql-insert statements such that one could execute these as inserts scripts to load a relevant subset into another DB for analysis.

Does such a tool exist? I could imagine that this is not such a seldom and exotic wish or requirement. Or is this wishful dreaming and I am in for a longer programming exercise?
The DB we are using is Oracle (v12) - in case that matters.

Hope I could make myself clear and convey the intention.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I did this and it was very easy because I had object-relational mapping to java objects.  I could just pick up the "parent" object from source db [which would recursively traverse all the relationships and pick up all the children], open a connection to the target DB and save the fully instantiated parent object tree.  I don't know of any other tools.  Folks in my company try to keep a pre-prd DB periodically refreshed from prod.

Taking hours to manually reproduce the problem conditions in the data seems like a long time, but so would hand building a custom solution.

If you are having data problems, it is likely a bug in the code, so if you can get developers to "write the test that fails" based on the conditions, you'll be better off.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was already considering using Hibernate to do this (which - as you write - would at least do the extraction almost for free), although emitting that stuff in some reusable format like sql inserts would be a bit of work. That's why I was wondering whether (and hoping that) there is some tool/utility that does that already out of the box. The downside of a Hibernate solution is that it's DB schema specific (at least I would not know otherwise). A generic tool would be cool!

Comment: @mmo  In my case, I was using TopLink for Java as the O-R mapping tool and I had a duplicate schema in another instance.  I can't recall the exact classes/methods, but with the "save/persist" mechanism all I had to do was open a new connection to the other instance with the schema that mapped to the objects, and save the high level object and the O-R mapping tool took care of the rest.